# Crash logging in iOS swift applications

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

We are developing an iOS application using swift.  We've been searching for an equivalent to NSUncaughtExceptionHandler, and have been unable to find anything.  From what i see by searching, swift itself does not support this due to design decisions.

However, libraries like firebase and crashalytics are able to detect swift based crashes (like the below would generate) and send logs to their services.

```
   [][1]
```

I'm wondering how they do this, as i'd like to be able to detect these and log them in whatever fashion our app wants.

I've looked into plcrashreporter, but am finding relatively minimal (if any) documentation on how to integrate it into swift.  I gave it a shot, but my handler is never firing:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

...
    let crashReporter = PLCrashReporter.shared()
    if (crashReporter?.hasPendingCrashReport())! {
        handleCrashReport()
    }

    var crashReporterCapture = PLCrashReporterCallbacks()
    crashReporterCapture.version = 0
    crashReporterCapture.context = nil
    let callback : PLCrashReporterPostCrashSignalCallback = { info, uap, ctx in
        handleCrashReport()
    }

    crashReporterCapture.handleSignal =  callback
    crashReporter?.setCrash(&crashReporterCapture)
    crashReporter?.enable()
```

Comment: did you ever solved this? Is so, Could you share how did you do it? I think I have the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67819590/how-to-set-plcrashreporter-setcrashcallbacks-in-swift