# How to set PLCrashReporter.setCrashCallbacks in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, crash-reports

I am trying to call setup PLCrashReporter with `setCrashCallbacks` in swift but somehow the callback is apparently not called. I can see all my NSLog calls appearing in Console.app. I also can see the report in text format in the next launch. However I NSLog call inside the callback never shows in Console.app.

How can I do this in Swift? Is it even possible to do this in Swift? or I need to go the Objetive-C ?

```swift
// Added via SPM
import CrashReporter

// global scope function
func handleSignalForCrashReport(_ siginfo: UnsafeMutablePointer<siginfo_t>?, _ context: UnsafeMutablePointer<ucontext_t>?, _ something: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    // This never shows ?
    NSLog("crash rep handleSignalForCrashReport")

    // Do my thing here ...
}

// global scope variable
var callbacks = PLCrashReporterCallbacks(version: 0, context: nil, handleSignal: handleSignalForCrashReport)

class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {


    func setupCrashReporter() {

        let config = PLCrashReporterConfig(signalHandlerType: .mach, symbolicationStrategy: .all)
        NSLog("crash rep 1")
        guard let crashReporter = PLCrashReporter(configuration: config) else {
            NSLog("crash rep 1.1")
            return
        }
        NSLog("crash rep 2")

        crashReporter.setCrash(&callbacks)
        do {
            try crashReporter.enableAndReturnError()
            NSLog("crash rep 3")
        } catch {
            NSLog("crash rep 4 Warning: Could not enable crash reporter: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if crashReporter.hasPendingCrashReport() {
            do {
                let data = try crashReporter.loadPendingCrashReportDataAndReturnError()
                let report = try PLCrashReport(data: data)
                guard let reportText = PLCrashReportTextFormatter .stringValue(for: report, with: PLCrashReportTextFormatiOS) else {
                    NSLog("crash rep 5 report text nil")
                    return
                }
                NSLog("crash rep 6 previous report: \(reportText)")
                try crashReporter.purgePendingCrashReportAndReturnError()
                NSLog("crash rep 7")
            } catch {
                NSLog("crash rep Error: \(error)")
            }
        }
        NSLog("crash rep finished installation")
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        setupCrashReporter()

        return true
    }
```

BTW This is the [objective-C demo file](https://github.com/microsoft/plcrashreporter/blob/master/Other%20Sources/Crash%20Demo/main.m) from the official repository where I got ideas from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not find a good way of working with PLCrashReporter. After of spending various days investigating I eventually end up moving to KSCrash which is quite nice and highly extensible.

If anybody has a solution for PLCrashReported I will happily make it the answer ✅

```
import KSCrash_Installations
import KSCrash_Recording

KSCrash.sharedInstance().deleteBehaviorAfterSendAll = KSCDeleteNever
KSCrash.sharedInstance()?.maxReportCount = 1
        
// MyCrashInstallation could be any subclass of KSCrashInstallation
var installation: KSCrashInstallation? = MyCrashInstallation.shared
installation?.appleReportStyle = KSAppleReportStyleUnsymbolicated
installation?.install()
installation?.onCrash = { writer in
    let userId:String = "example123"
    let now = "20210831"
    writer?.pointee.addStringElement(writer, "my_key_userid", "\(userId)")
    writer?.pointee.addStringElement(writer, "my_error_date", "\(now)")
}
```